# Google Sheets Android - Continuing Formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have the formula `B6=((A6/A4)*B4)+A2` and I want to copy it throughout the rest of the column so that:
`B7=((A7/A4)*B4)+A2`,`B8=((A8/A4)*B4)+A2`, and so on. I know how I would do this on a computer but I do not have access to one. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

1. Tap on your formula `B6=((A6/A4)*B4)+A2` to select it, then tap
   another time to select `COPY`
2. Tap on the column name `B` to select the whole column, then tap
       again on it to `PASTE` the formula.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

1. Make at least two cells with continuing formula
2. Copy the two cells, and the paste in the next two cells and then repeat with four cells.

Answer (score 1):

This approach is for when you don't want to paste the formula on the whole column.

1. Tap on the cell containing the formula to select it, then tap again and select COPY
2. Select all the cells you'll want to paste the formula then tap on any of the selected cells
3. Select PASTE SPECIAL, then select PASTE FORMULA ONLY.